# jQuery Lazy Load: Div inside Div inside Div

Tags: jquery, css, html, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use [jQuery Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) plugin, but it says

> You can also use plugin for images inside scrolling container, such as div with scrollbar. Just pass the container as jQuery object.

Ok, my problem is: I have a nest of divs, and the scrollable is the outer, but the image is in the inner div. Example:

```
<div class="outer">
   ...
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="inner">
        <img ... />
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
        <img ... />
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
        <img ... />
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I do a Lazy Loading with these guys?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Here is a `scrollable` example that fixed it.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/dragoncrew/SHGwe/1/

```
var ds_loaded = false, 
    top = $("#disqus_thread").offset().top;
window.disqus_developer = 1;
window.disqus_shortname = 'dragoncrew';

function check(){
    if ( !ds_loaded && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > top ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/embed.js",
            dataType: "script",
            cache: true
        });
        ds_loaded = true;
    }
}

$(window).scroll(check);

check();
```

Comment: ok, so your solution uses ajax instead of the plugin i'm using now. interesting, i'll try to adapt my case to ajax!

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I've found a simple and clean solution to solve my problem with minimum amount of code, it is here:
[Delay Image Loading With JQuery](http://www.peterhintondesign.co.uk/journal/delay-image-loading-with-jquery/).

The url is just stored at the **name** attribute of the img, and when I need to actually load the image, I load this url to the **src** attribute.

Maybe this is not the most appropriate solution for SEO, but my page is not tracked by search engines, and this works like a charm to speed up loading.